# How to allow multiple users to refresh to sharepoint Excel file with Power Query

Tags: microsoft-excel, sharepoint, power-query

I have an excel file with data and the second excel file that uses Power Query to connect and fetch data from that 'data' file. They both are located in the Sharepoint space.

When I set up a connection, I use "Organization account Sign In" with organizational type, with my account and everything works fine, I can refresh the connection then. However, when someone else tries to refresh it after I save the file, he gets "`microsoft.mashup.engine.interface.resource access forbiddenexception`". Clearing the permissions does not help. Yet people do have permissions to access this scape and file.

Is there any solution to that? Thanks.

Comment: The other user needs to go in and clear the permissions, then connect using the Organization account Sign In, like you did initially, it took me a few goes to set other users up for this, and you will need to do this on every connection, as the saved credentials won't work accross the whole sheet.

Comment: @PeterH thanks, looks like clearing the permissions worked. But it will be enough for each user to enter their credentials once (on the first refresh) in the file? They won't be required to do this each time they open the file, right?

Comment: I often create workbooks, and then they are only ever ran by a dedicated user, and they only need to clear and enter once, not quite sure how it works with multiple users, if you work it all out, please post up as an answer to help me and others with the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Each user will have to set credentials, its a security restriction that you cant share your credentials with others.

You can smooth this process by always starting your queries using the **SharePoint Folder** connector, rather than **Web**. From that starting point, edit your query to filter the list of files in the SP site by folder and/or file name, then click on the **Binary** cell in the **Content** column to open the Excel file you want to read from.

When all your queries are using the **SharePoint Folder** connector, each user only has to set credentials once per SharePoint site, rather than once for each file.

Comment: Thanks, did not know about SharepointFolder, sounds much smoother, will give it a try!

Comment: Hi, can you share some more on the sharepoint connector please ? i've never used or even saw this, great answer +1

Comment: From the Excel Data ribbon, choose Get Data / From File / From SharePoint Folder. Paste in the site root URL (not a document library or folder URL). Credentials are typically Microsoft account - same one  you use to sign on to SharePoint. Returns a list of all the files in the site.